# How to set tolerance in Python Sympy to treat nearly equal floats as equal?

Tags: python, sympy, precision

In essence, I am running into the following problem. Suppose I have some symbolic expressions in Python Sympy given by

```
expr1 = a * x + b
expr2 = c * x + b
```

where a,c,b are some floats and x is an actual symbol. The only thing you need to know is that the difference between a and c is negligible, i.e. their difference is in the order of 10^{-16}.

For example, I consider the following:

```
a = 2.924950591148529
c = 2.92495059114853
```

If I now consider the expression

```
result = sympy.cancel(expr1/expr2)
```

and print all of the code, I would get the following output:

```
2.92495059114853*x + 1
2.92495059114853*x + 1
(2.92495059114853*x + 1.0)/(2.92495059114853*x + 1.0)
```

Just looking at the output, you would expect the last line to be 1.0. This is of course not the case, since a does not exactly equal c.

**My question is: how do I make it so that sympy/python considers a and c to be the same thing. In other words "how do I lower the tolerance" in a sense?**

If I now consider for example

```
result.subs(x, PUT SOME NUMBER HERE)
```

the output will be something like 1.0000 or 0.9999999998 everytime. This is fine.

Why this poses is a problem is because in the more specific case (that I will not include in this question), I will eventually consider expressions like (mind you, this is just a MWE to highlight the problem):

```
first = expr1 / expr2 / expr1 / expr2
second = expr2 / expr1 / expr2 / expr1 

# Perform cancellation
result = sympy.cancel(first/second/first/second/first/second/second/first/second/first/second)
```

If I now consider the following:

```
print(result.subs(x, 10))
```

the output is

```
4.497064709891226e+26
```

while the actual value that I would like to have is 1.

To reproduce what I just mentioned, here is the code in full for your convenience:

```
import sympy as sp

# Values
a = 2.924950591148529
c = 2.92495059114853

# Define the symbolic variables and expressions
x = sp.symbols('x')
expr1 = a*x + 1
expr2 = c*x + 1

# Replace coefficients within the specified tolerance
first = expr1 / expr2 / expr1 / expr2
second = expr2 / expr1 / expr2 / expr1 

# Perform cancellation
result = sp.cancel(first/second/first/second/first/second/second/first/second/first/second) 

# Input value
print(result.subs(x, 10))
```

P.S.
In the more specific setting where I run into this issue, it is actually that the coefficient a is given, and c is calculated using sympy solve. Another solution to my specific problem would be increase the precision of sympy solve so that c is the same as a. However, I found that would warrant a different thread. But for full context, this might be nice to know.

Comment: You can use `nsimplify(expr/expr2)`. In general though for things like `cancel` I recommend avoiding floats altogether so the actual solution to your problem is to trace it back to where the floats came from and do something differently.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I don't really see how `nsimplify` would help in this case. I nevertheless tried using it out, and it doesn't solve the issue as I suspected.

Although I understand the suggestion to only use symbols, I believe that the original situation from which I extracted this question would involve way too many variables to make it workable. I will take another look though, who knows it's a possible solution!

Comment: With numpy arrays, we use `np.isclose` and `np.allclose` to compare float arrays.  Roughly this does `np.max(np.abs(x-y))`, and checks that against absolute and relative tolerances (default or user specified).  This recognizes that floats, especially arrays of floats, are rarely, if ever, exactly the same, regardless of precision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have a logical error, not a problem with precision. Let `a` and `c` be Symbols:

```py
a, c = sp.symbols('a c')
x = sp.symbols('x')
expr1 = a*x + 1
expr2 = c*x + 1
first = expr1 / expr2 / expr1 / expr2
second = expr2 / expr1 / expr2 / expr1 
result = sp.cancel(first/second/first/second/first/second/second/first/second/first/second)
```

Your factored `result` is then

```py
>>> factor(result)
(a*x + 1)**12*(c*x + 1)**6
>>> _.subs(a, c)  # assume a and c are the same
(c*x + 1)**18
```

So even if `a == c`, if it is near 3 and you multiply by `x=10` you are going to get `31**18` which is on the order of `10**26` (like you got). If you want to treat `a` and `c` as basically the same, round them the same:

```py
>>> a = 2.924950591148529
>>> c = 2.92495059114853
>>> a, c = [i.round(15) for i in Tuple(a,c)]
>>> print('a==c is %s'%Eq(a,c))
a==c is True
```

(But again -- your problem in not getting a result close to 1 is not precision related.)

Comment: You are right. I was trying to reproduce an error that I had in some other case, but it seems I made a mistake in trying to reproduce it. Solving the "logical error" (which comes down properly defining `first` and `second` so expressions that would actually equal 1 if a == c, does not reproduce the problem that I posed.

I will revisit the issue that I have in my project for which I tried to generalize using this question. Thank you for pointing that out.

In my particular setting, it is impossible to round a and c to some expression. For that reason, that wouldn't have been a solution.

Comment: You can do a replacement of `a` and `c` in the `result` with values that have been rounded. So although you can't control what comes *into* the result, you can control what happens to the result when you want it evaluated as though `a == c`: `result.xreplace({i: i.round(15) for i in (a, c)})`.